# Is there a way to extract folders from a repo with full history?

Tags: git

I have a repo with lots of Visual Studio projects that I want to extract to their own solution and repo but I don't want to loose history.

Is there a way to create a repo from the current one with full history but only the folders I choose?

I could clone the repo and remove what I don't want, but I was hoping to save some space.

Answer (score 3):

The process is described [here](https://help.github.com/articles/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository/). If you do not need to work with GitHub (or any other hosting service), steps 1 to 5 should suffice.

Comment: As I need to keep sibling directories, `--subdirectory-filter` doesn't seem to be a good choice.

Comment: Will the commit hashes remain the same?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it doesn't look so. See [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch): `WARNING! The rewritten history will have different object names for all the objects and will not converge with the original branch. You will not be able to easily push and distribute the rewritten branch on top of the original branch. Please do not use this command if you do not know the full implications, and avoid using it anyway, if a simple single commit would suffice to fix your problem.`

Comment: It does change the repo into what I want but looses the history. Is there a way to keep the history?

Comment: Do you want to keep the history for the *whole* repository, or just for the parts you extracted? And by "keep the history", you mean information about what changes happened or the exact commits from the original repository?

Comment: I want to keep the information about all the changes on the files I kept.

Answer (score 1):

Create multiple copies of the Git repository folder on disk (one for each solution you want to extract) and then use **[BFG Repo-Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/)** to remove all folders that do not belong to each folder, effectively rewriting the history on each repo leaving only the files you want (and preserving their history).

Answer (score 1):

`git filter-branch` now recommends using an alternative to itself! (checked at git version 2.26)

```
$ git filter-branch --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter ...
WARNING: git-filter-branch has a glut of gotchas generating mangled history
     rewrites.  Hit Ctrl-C before proceeding to abort, then use an
     alternative filtering tool such as 'git filter-repo'
     (https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/) instead.  See the
     filter-branch manual page for more details; to squelch this warning
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the patch file

```
cd ~/repository/path
git log --pretty=email --patch-with-stat --reverse --full-index --binary -- path/to/file_or_folder > /tmp/patc
```

Path replacements if needed

```
sed -i -e 's/deep\/path\/that\/you\/want\/shorter/short\/path/g' /tmp/patch
```

Commit to the new repo

```
cd ~/another_repository/path
git am < /tmp/patch
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @kowsky answer, you can use [git-filter-branch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) to accomplish the same, as follows:

```
git clone https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY-NAME
cd REPOSITORY-NAME
git remote rm origin
git filter-branch --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter FOLDER-NAME BRANCH-NAME
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/USERNAME/NEW-REPOSITORY-NAME.git
git push -u origin BRANCH-NAME
```

Comment: is FOLDER-NAME the one I want to remove or keep?

Comment: I've also tried something like `git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm status' HEAD` but I always get `rm: cannot remove 'status': No such file or directory`.

Comment: `FOLDER-NAME` is the one which you want to keep.

Comment: It does change the repo into what I want but looses the history. Is there a way to keep the history?